# Create Bond Using React-native-ble-plx

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, react-native-ble-plx

calling `monitorCharacteristicForService` disconnect BLE Device in Android with below error

**{"message":"Device xx:xx:xx:xx was disconnected","errorCode":201,"attErrorCode":19,"iosErrorCode":null,"androidErrorCode":null,"reason":"Disconnected from xx:xx:xx:xx with status 19 (UNKNOWN)","name":"BleError","line":24096,"column":28,"sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"}**

**What need to be done:**

createBond with BLE Device

Ideas required how to create a bond with Device manually

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx

Version 2.0.2 It does NOT support:

- bluetooth classic devices.
- communicating between phones using BLE (Peripheral support)
- bonding peripherals